# How to highlight HTML element on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mouseevent

Is it possible to write code in JavaScript that highlights the borders of the HTML element on which the mouse pointer stands (or clicks), in a similar way to what [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) does, but without the use of a browser extension but rather rely on JavaScript alone?

If so, is it possible to get the relevant element from HTML code after the mouse click on element?

[edit] Thanks for the answers! is it possible to run those examples on *external page* (rather than on a page that I created) without the use of things like GreaseMonkey?

Comment: @Marcel — Firebug has access to the extensions APIs which code executing in a webpage does not, so that does not necessarily follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example. You should be able to build upon this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;

    // this is the element you want:
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```

This method would probably be more preferred:

```
var hilightElement = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;

    // this is the element you want:
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
};

if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener('click', hilightElement, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent){
    document.attachEvent('onclick', hilightElement);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Listen for click events on the `document` object. You can then examine the event object to find out which element was clicked, and then alter its CSS `border` or `outline` as desired.

A very simple example, that doesn't try to account for cross browser compatibility problems would be:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.style.outline = "solid blue 1px";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for JQuery:

```
$('#myElement'/* Replace with asterisk if you want it to work for every element */).click
(
    function()
    {
        $(this).css('outline', '1px solid red');
    }
);
```

Comment: Oh no, you really shouldn't attach event listeners to all available elements. It's better to attach one handler to `document` and get the clicked element using the Event interface. Moreover, he didn't ask for a jQuery solution.